# How to remove or force lock specific android system activity without root?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dns

There are "private DNS" feature in MIUI 12.0.8 mobiles

Now i want to force my mobile to use specific private DNS for ever and no one can change it, not even me

How can i remove (or disable or powerful lock) below activity in my mobile that nobody can recover or change it for ever? (As the only recover way is to flash a new ROM)

> com.android.settings.network.PrivateDnsSettingsActivity

I search this problem but all of solution need root
I need a solution without root or I need android app vault that can lock android specific activity

My ultimate goal is that my mobile use specific private DNS forever that no one, not even me, can change.